# Man hours calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi this might be a simple question.. But someone please explain me how to do this..

It takes 4 hours to complete a task for a man. For another person it takes 6 hours. Another person will complete the same task within 3 hours.

If all these people get together how many time will it be taken to complete the whole task

Answer (score 1):

I won't do the problem for you, but I will show you how to think about it. In *one* hour, how much of the job is accomplished by each of the three people? So how much is accomplished by all three working together? Now figure out how many hours are required to complete the task.